# Connection between the mishkan and the egel hazahav

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, golden-calf-egel, parshanut-torah-comment

Do you guys know of any sources that connect the physical construction of the egel with the construction of the mishkan - both are made of gold and the beginning of parshat terumah starts by talking about giving gold for the mishkan but are there other connections? I ask this because I remember hearing about the connections in the past but cannot seem to find them either in the text or in safrut chazal. A little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: The _mishkan_ was made partially of gold, but not chiefly, whereas the calf was gold. In any event, welcome to mi.yodeya.com, Ariel; I hope you enjoy it and stick around. Consider completing registration for the site, by clicking "Register", above.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that has struck me — but that, in my limited experience and AFAIR, I haven't seen anyone mention — is that the *m'nora* of the *mishkan* was, according to a *midrash* (cited by *Rashi* to 25:31), created miraculously automatically when unshaped gold was thrown into fire and that *Aharon*, according to the *Mizrachi* (quoted in *Sifse Chachamim* to 32:24), lied and said that that was how the *egel* had been made.

Answer (score 2):

*K'li Yakar* to 35:22 notes that the men, who had sinned by donating their jewelry toward the *egel*'s construction, needed the penance of donating such items toward the *mishkan*'s, but the women, who hadn't done so, didn't need it; nonetheless, the women donated their jewelry toward the *mishkan*, which the Torah mentions there in their honor.